Failure verifying a X.509 Certificate although its not been tampered
I am doing an assignment where I have a CA (server) and a client that requests a certificate from the CA, this function works. The certificate is sent via tcp as bytes. The idea is that clients will share a session key, but before they do they need to verify each others certificates. I do not have two clients set up so I decided to verify the clients own certificate using the function I created. Yet it somehow says the certificate is invalid even though I am verifying a certificate I just got from the CA:
Here is my function:
def verifyCert(certificate):
   
    certificatetoRead = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(certificate, default_backend())
    public_key = certificatetoRead.public_key()

    try:
        public_key.verify(
            certificatetoRead.signature,
            certificatetoRead.tbs_certificate_bytes,
            padding.PKCS1v15(),
            certificatetoRead.signature_hash_algorithm,
        )
        
        print("Certificate signature verified. It's legitimate.")
    except Exception:
        print("Certificate signature verification failed. It may be tampered or invalid.")  

When the CA sends me the certificate, I pass it to this verifyCert function, and because I've not done anything, I'm expecting it to verify it and say it is legitimate but it says its tampered.
Could I please get help as to what I may be doing wrong?

Is it possible that you mix up self-signed certificates with those signed by a CA? Only for self-signed certificates the public key of the cert is the one used to verify the certificate signature. For CA generated certificates the public key you need to use is the one from the CA not for the certificate itself.
